# C graphics: How to draw x-y axis on screen?

Tags: c, graphics, 2d

I found this code for the same.But i am not getting what is being done.Can someone explain me the code?
Here xmid=getmaxx()/2  and ymid=getmaxy()/2 .
I want to know why we are using these for loops? Why itoa() function is used?

```
line(5,ymid,getmaxx()-5,ymid);
line(xmid+3,5,xmid+3,getmaxy()-5);

for( i= xmid+gap;i<getmaxx()-5;i=i+gap)
{
outtextxy(i,ymid-3,"|");
itoa(i-xmid,str,10);
outtextxy(i,ymid+3,str);
}
for( i= ymid-gap;i>5;i=i-gap)
{
outtextxy(xmid,i,"-");
itoa(ymid-i,str,10);
outtextxy(xmid+5,i,str);

}
for( i= xmid-gap;i>5;i=i-gap)
{

outtextxy(i,ymid-3,"|");
itoa(-(xmid-i),str,10);
outtextxy(i-6,ymid+3,str);

}
for( i= ymid+gap;i<getmaxy()-5;i=i+gap)
{
outtextxy(xmid,i,"-");
itoa(-(i-ymid),str,10);
outtextxy(xmid+8,i,str);
}
```

Comment: what platform are you running on (Windows, Mac, Linux, DOS)?  Also what graphics package are you using (OpenGL, DirectX, native)?

Comment: I am using DOS based Turbo C/C++

Comment: I was in training for the past few days, so I didn't have time to get back to this.  I posted an answer with my analysis of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat to this answer: I don't own Turbo C/C++ so this answer is based on looking up the function definitions and signatures and piecing stuff together from there.

(1) `itoa` is a non-standard C function (microsoft specific?) that converts an integer value into a string.  It have the signature: `char* itoa(int, char* int);`.  It takes the value in the first argument and converts it into the character array in the second argument.  The final integer argument is the base that the used to convert the string.  For example, if `int b = 33` we would have:

```
    char buf[33];
    itoa(b, buf, 10);      // buf would contain  '3', '3', '0'
    itoa(b, buf, 16);      // buf would contain   '2', '1', '0'
    itoa(b, buf,  2);      // buf would contain  '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0','1'
```

(2) the outtextxy function is used to draw a string on the screen, and has the function signature `outtextxy(int x, int y, char* string);`  The fist to parameters give the x and y coordinates (in pixels) of where the string is going to start.

(3) The line function is used to draw a line on the screen and has the function signature `line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);` where the first two arguments are the x and y coordinates (in pixels) for the first starting point, and the last two coordinates (in pixels) are for the final point.

(4) `getmaxx()` and `getmaxy()` return the width and height of your screen in pixels, based on the resolution.  So if you are running at 1024 x 768 resolution, `getmaxx()` would return 1024 and `getmaxy()` would return 768

Knowing what the individual functions do, we can analyze the code snippet:

```
    line(5,ymid,getmaxx()-5,ymid);
```

This draws a line, in the middle of the screen, starting 5 pixels from the left hand side and extending to 5 pixels from the right had side.  Not seeing the full code, I have to make the assumption that `ymid` is the mid point of the screen, *i.e.* `int ymid = getmaxy()/2;`

```
    line(xmid+3,5,xmid+3,getmaxy()-5);
```

Making a similar assumption that `int xmid = getmaxx();`, then this function draws a vertical line from 5 pixels below to top of the screen to 5 pixels above the bottom of the screen.  Also, note that we offset `xmid` by 3, so this line will be off-center by three pixels to the right.  With out seeing more of the code or the context for this snippet, I have no idea why the original author choose to do this.

```
    for( i= xmid+gap;i<getmaxx()-5;i=i+gap)
    {
        outtextxy(i,ymid-3,"|");
        itoa(i-xmid,str,10);
        outtextxy(i,ymid+3,str);
    }
```

We don't know what the value of `gap` is but for the sake of argument, lets assume that it is 20, and also assume that our screen resolution is 1024 x 768.  With these assumptions, we can conclude the following:

1. `xmid` is going to be 512
2. `getmaxx()` will return 1024
3. `i` will start at 532 and run till it exceeds 1024 in steps of 20.

From this we know that `i` will have the sequence {532, 552, 572, .... , 992, 1032}.  With this, we can look at the next line of code and see that the outtext is going to draw a '|' using each of the above i values and the x coordinate and using a y value of `ymid-3`.  My best guess on this line of code is that it is responsible for drawing tick marks at `gap` intervals a few pixels below the x-axis.

In the next line, the value `i-xmid` will just return the distance from the center, and convert it into a string.  So for example, the first time through the loop `i` will be 532, and if we subtract `xmid` we will get 20, and we will cause `str` to have the value "20".  Thus this line of code is just generating the label for a tick mark.

The final line in the body of the for-loop will print out the string at the correct location, notice the values for x and y in the outtextxy function call, so the label is printed a few pixel above the x-axis.

I didn't analyze the other three loops, but I suspect that they are doing the same thing, drawing tick marks on the axis's.  We use four for loops to deal with the positive and negative directions on each axis.

Comment: Thanx for the explaination. It was a great help.